# virtual function overhead when deterministic (c++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I know that virtual functions are essentially function pointers contained on a vtable, which makes polymorphic calls slower because of indirection etc.
But I'm wondering about compiler optimisation when call is deterministic.
By deterministic, I mean the following cases:

1. The object is a value and not a reference, so there is no polymorphism possible:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void DoSomething(){....}
};

int main()
{
    Foo myfoo;
    myfoo.DoSemthing();
    return 0;
}
```

2. The reference is to a childless class:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void DoSomething();
};
struct Bar : public Foo
{
   virtual void DoSomething();
};

int main()
{
    Foo* a = new Foo();
    a->DoSomething(); //Overhead ? a doesn't seem to be able to change nature.

    Foo* b = new Bar();
    b->DoSomething(); //Overhead ? It's a polymorphic call, but b's nature is deterministic.

    Bar* c = new Bar();
    c->DoSomething(); //Overhead ? It is NOT possible to have an other version of the method than Bar::DoSomething
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no polymorphism for values, thus I dont really understand what you mean with a).

Comment: There is no difference between `Foo* a = new Foo()` and `Foo* b = new Foo()`. What are you trying to illustrate here?

Comment: These are all potentially optimizable since the dynamic type of `a`, `b`, and `c` are all known at compile time. Whether compilers actually perform the optimization is another matter. As Yam Marcovic noted, this is an active field of research, so the state of the art is constantly changing.

Comment: You're wondering about compiler optimizations but I'm wondering what your question is and what you have done yourself in order to answer it...

Answer (score 9):

In the first case, this will not be a virtual call. The compiler will issue a call straight to `Foo::DoSomething()`.

In the second case, it's more complicated. For one, it's at-best a link time optimization, since for a specific translation unit, the compiler doesn't know who else might inherit from that class. The other problem you get is with shared libraries which might also inherit without your executable knowing anything about it.

In general, though, this a compiler optimization known as *virtual function call elimination*, or *devirtualization*, and is somewhat of an active field of research. Some compilers do it to some extent, others don't do it at all.

See, in GCC (g++), `-fdevirtualize` and `-fdevirtualize-speculatively`. The names kind of hint at the guaranteed level of quality.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2013, a virtual function call is not optimized even when the behavior is deterministic.

For example,

```
#include <iostream>

static int counter = 0;

struct Foo
{
    virtual void VirtualCall() { ++counter; }
    void RegularCall() { ++counter; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo* a = new Foo();
    a->VirtualCall(); //Overhead ? a doesn't seem to be able to change nature.
    a->RegularCall();
    std::cout << counter;
    return 0;
}
```

The machine code for the virtual call looks like this:

```
a->VirtualCall()

  0001b 8b 01        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx]
  0001d ff 10        call    DWORD PTR [eax]
```

The machine code for the regular call shows that the function was inlined - there was no function call:

```
 a->RegularCall()

  00         inc     DWORD PTR _counter
```

Comment: Is this the result when using O3?

Comment: I know almost nothing about assembly. Is this (for virtual call) a call to a "function pointer" ro waht looks the most like it in assembly ?

Answer (score 1):

In general you can trust your compiler optimiser to make the good choice, depending of course on the optimisation settings.

For the proof of concept, here a code using the different cases, `Foo` and `Bar` being defined as you did:

```
struct Tzar : public Foo
{
   void DoSomething() override final;  // this is a virtual than can't be overriden further
};

Foo* factory ();  
Bar* bar_factory(); 
Tzar* tsar_factory(); 

int main()
{
    Foo myfoo;
    myfoo.DoSomething();  // this is a direct call

    Foo* a = new Foo();
    a->DoSomething();  //Overhead only without optimisation: a is clearly a Foo, so Foo::DoSomething(). 

    Foo* b = new Bar();
    b->DoSomething(); //Overhead only without optimisation:  b is clearly a Bar, so Bar::DoSomething().

    Bar* c = new Bar();
    c->DoSomething(); //Overhead only without optimisation: c is clearly a Bar, so Bar::DoSomething

    Foo* d = factory(); 
    d->DoSomething();  // Overhead required:  we don't know the type of d, unless global optimisation could predict it

    a = d; 
    a->DoSomething();  //the unknown propagates to a, so now this call is indirect 

    Foo*e = bar_factory(); 
    e->DoSomething();  // Overhead required:  we don't know the type of e: could be a Bar or a furhter derivate unknown in this compilation unit

    Foo*f = tsar_factory(); 
    f->DoSomething();  // Overhead could be optimised away : we don't know the type of f, but f::DoSomething() can't be overriden further
                       // but currently it isn't

  return 0;
}
```

You can find [here the assembly code](https://goo.gl/kh3UC2) generated for all the cases you have submitted using GCC 5.3.0 without optimisation.  It is colourised to help you seeing the assembler code for each C++ statement.

The first call will always be a direct call:

```
    lea     rax, [rbp-80]         ;  take the object pointer from the stack
    mov     rdi, rax              ;  set the this pointer of the invoking object
    call    Foo::DoSomething()    ; direct call to the function
```

Without optimisation, all the other invocations of `DoSomething()` will use the indirect call.  here the example of the `b->DoSomething()`:

```
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]  ; load the function call from the vtable
    mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-32]
    mov     rdi, rax              ;  set the this pointer of the invoking object
    call    rax                   ; indirect call via register
```

If you now set the optimizing flag -O2 in the compiler option, you'll see that most indirect calls get optimized away, when the compiler can predict the real type of the polymorphic pointer.  In the example above, it will be:

```
    mov     rdi, rax            ;  set the this pointer of the invoking object
    call    Bar::DoSomething()  ; direct call !!
```

When the compiler is not able to safely predict the real type, it will use the indirect call.  For example, if you have a function  `bar_factory()`, which returns a `Bar` pointer, the compiler can't know if it will return a pointer to a `Bar` object or to an object of a class derived from `Bar` (which could be defined in another compilation unit and not known here).

The only unexpected point is when you define a virtual function to be the final override (`Tzar` class in my example).  Here you could expect that  the compiler would take advantage of the fact that `DoSomething()` is not supposed to get derived further.  But it's not necessarily done.